# What does "up in this grill" mean?

Tags: african-american-vernacular-english

In an episode of "The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air", Will Smith says:

> What we gotta do, is get up in this grill and show 'em that we've got the power!

I've checked Wiktionary and Urban Dictionary, but I find no suitable meaning.

What is a "grill" in this context? Clearly not a girl or a contraption for cooking food.

Comment: More context is needed here. "Grill" as slang in AmE dialects typically refers to a vehicle's grill or the facemask of an American football helmet. Whether either or neither of these meanings is intended here depends on the scene and the surrounding dialogue.

Comment: Can you link to the transcript or a video or at least the specific episode number?

Answer (score 1):

If what was said is "their grill" or "his grill", it's a statement about confrontation. The grill in this case is one's face, as an analogy to the grille of a car.

If it really was "that grill" then we'd need more context to know what the antecedent of "that" is.

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+in+his+grill) has this sense of grill

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing it was "his grill".

Comment: Yes, the grille-grill connection is the set of teeth — by extension, show of teeth, mouth, face: get in his face.